# extract last day and first day from month in python

Tags: python-3.x

i am new in python ,i have a string of this format

```
Ex. 'Mar-00'
```

how could i calculate first day and last day from this month.

**OUTPUT :**

```
first day : 01-Mar-00

last day : 31-Mar-00
```

**ex : 'Feb-17'**

```
first day : 01-Feb-17

last day : 28-Feb-17
```

Comment: do you want the output as Time/Datetime object or simply a string

Comment: as Time/Datetime object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]` to get the number of days in a given month+year.

the first is alway 01, and last is the value of `calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]`

try this, let me know if it works:

```py
import calendar

month_abbr_to_num = {v: k for k,v in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr)}

month_abbr, year_2_digit = input("please enter month, e.g. Mar-00:  ").split('-')

month = month_abbr_to_num[month_abbr]
year = int('20'+year_2_digit)

days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(year,month)[1]

print("first day : {:02d}-{}-{}".format(1, month_abbr, year_2_digit))
print("last day : {:02d}-{}-{}".format(days_in_month, month_abbr, year_2_digit))
```

**EDIT:**

following your comment on original question, here it is in the form of a function that returns both as `datetime` objects:

```py
import calendar
import datetime

month_abbr_to_num = {v: k for k,v in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr)}

def get_first_and_last_day(user_input):
    month_abbr, year_2_digit = user_input.split('-')
    month = month_abbr_to_num[month_abbr]
    year = int('20' + year_2_digit)
    days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
    first_day = datetime.datetime(year, month, 1)
    last_day = datetime.datetime(year, month, days_in_month)
    return first_day, last_day



first, last = get_first_and_last_day(input("please enter month, e.g. Mar-00:  "))

print("first day : ",first)
print("last day : ",last)
```

Comment: where i have to put Mar-00 in this calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1] formula

Comment: @gm_datascience I edited my answer with an example usage

Comment: If i enter the month 'Mar-99' then its showing 2099 year , what should i do